# How to host blog under /blog under my www domain while blog resides at blog.example.com

Tags: wordpress, iis

I have a nopCommerce website at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) hosted on dedicated windows server with IIS, and hosted my wordpress blog on cPanel shared server with url blog.example.com.

So I have my website at https://www.example.com/ and blog at https://blog.example.com/ which works fine.

Now I want to make my blog accessible at https://www.example.com/blog and practically all my blog posts and related pages to accessible under https://www.example.com/blog/url-slug

Not sure how to do that. Pls guide.

Comment: Have you considered redirecting `https://blog.example.com` to `https://www.example.com/blog`? my idea is to host your blog in the subdirectory `blog` where `https://www.example.com` is located, and then use different sub-urls according to the content of each blog.

Comment: @samwu That's a good idea, but personally, I would do the reverse. IIS will often have a redirects module in place, so I think it would probably be easier to redirect `www.example.com/blog` to `blog.example.com`. This way, SEO will also be preserved on the `blog.example.com` domain and OP can keep his existing hosting on his cPanel server without having to monkey around with migrating everything over to IIS (which is notoriously difficult to work with for PHP apps).

Comment: I see you missed my question, I don't want redirection. I want my blog that is currently at blog.example.com to be open with url example.com/blog and all URLs rewritten like that. Not a redirection, but rewriting.

Comment: @Krunal I see you missed the answer: Look into the [Rewrite Module for IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module). It supports both URL redirects as well as rewrites.

Comment: I understand that, but how do we do that! I am not getting it.

Comment: You can achieve this by creating url rewrite rules.

Comment: Any idea how to do that exactly. I tried several rules but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you need? I will make demo for you.

Comment: I think I have already explained it in the question. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this demo as a reference, I redirect `https://blog.example.com` to `https://www.example.com/blog`:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^blog.example.com$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://www.example.com/blog" />
</rule>
```

Comment: What we need is not redirect but a rewrite!